# Multiple *ngFor counter

Tags: javascript, angular

For the following data:

```
const arr1 = ['Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3'];
const arr2 = ['Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3'];
const arr3 = ['Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3'];
```

And the following HTML:

```html
<div *ngFor="let val of arr1>
   {{val}}
</div>
<div *ngFor="let val of arr2>
   {{val}}
</div>
<div *ngFor="let val of arr3>
   {{val}}
</div>
```

I want to display

```
1. Val1
2. Val2
3. Val3
4. Val1
5. Val2
6. Val3
7. Val1
8. Val2
9. Val3
```

I know I can use `let i = index` and use something like `{{arr1.length + arr2.length + i}}` but I can have multiple arrays and the order of the display can change programatically. I want a smarter solution that doesn't involve knowing the exact number of arrays I am displaying. I want the counter to increase using the order of `*ngFor` execution in the HTML template.

Also I can have multiple `*ngFor` in one HTML template and I don't want to apply the counter to all of them. So I have 5 `*ngFor` but only 3 should have counters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that in this way, using only **single `*ngFor`**

Take an array variable and concatenate all arrays into it.

Then use that new array in HTML

**Your Component can be:**

```
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <div *ngFor="let val of array;let i = index;">
        {{i + 1}}.{{val}}
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  public array = [];
  constructor() {
    const arr1 = ['Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3'];
    this.array = this.array.concat(arr1);
    const arr2 = ['Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3'];
    this.array= this.array.concat(arr2)
    const arr3 = ['Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3'];
    this.array = this.array.concat(arr3)
    console.log(this.array)
  }
}
```

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/YhC2ZyZLD0OjuRQTkoh4?p=preview)

Comment: That can work but each array will have a different styling. Thanks anyway.

Comment: means? you havent mentioned that in the question. can u explain that more?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need multiple arrays like arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, ...

If this is the case, why not have a super array of arrays

```
const arr = [ ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'], [ 'val1', 'val2', 'val3'], ... ]
```

You can have two for loops for displaying this and it would work for n number of arrays

```
<div *ngFor="let a of arr">
    <div *ngFor="let b of a">
        {{ b }}
    </div>
</d>
```

Comment: That can work but each array will have a different styling. Thanks anyway.